# What may be inferred from structure of XML documents?

Tags: xml

Generally XML documents can be considered from two main aspects: Content and Structure.I'm wondering what type of information may be inferred from the structure of such documents?

Currently I know that XML schema/DTD could be reconstructed by analyzing the structure; Is that the main goal of preserving XML structure? If this is true, why the Schema is so important?

Comment: The schema is important for validation, i.e. checking if the XML is in the expected structure. As for the rest of your question: this is probably too broad to be answered here.

Comment: @helb, Thanks. Being more specific, is there any possibility for privacy breaches from schema/DTD?

Comment: @j.fra What kind of privacy breaches?

Comment: @biziclop, For example, confidential/ sensitive info about customers/patients who their information recorded in the document.

Comment: @j.fra I see. Well, looking at a schema defining the XML document you use to store these information we can deduce what kind of information you store about your customers, but not what the value of those fields is for any specific customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Generally XML documents can be considered from two main aspects:
>   Content and Structure

This is generally not a productive dichotomy.  Perhaps you're thinking of the separation between content and presentation, which is a productive distinction.

> Currently I know that XML schema/DTD could be reconstructed by
>   analyzing the structure

It is true that a schema can be written by looking at the structure of an XML instance document.  It is not true that a schema can be written at the correct level of abstraction for a category of XML instance documents given only a single XML instance document.

> Is that the main goal of preserving XML structure? If this is true,
>   why the Schema is so important?

Known structure facilitates communication of content.  A schema is important as a vehicle for expressing agreement over structure.

**Getting to your title question then:**

> What may be inferred from structure of XML documents?

Mostly what can be inferred is that which is separately conveyed in schemas, documentation, or the behavior of people or programs operating on the XML.

There are, however, some intrinsic relationships that arise due to the nature of XML itself:

- Containment and hierarchy can be inferred via the nesting of
  elements.
- Association can be inferred by attributes or positioning of elements.
- Meaning might be inferred by the naming of elements and attributes.

Comment: `Association can be inferred by attributes or positioning of elements.` In particular, arity can be guessed by looking at whether a property is an attribute or an element.

Comment: @kjhughes, Thanks for the answer, for sake of protection is there any way to secure , e.g. encrypt, schema? Such as information hiding for the content of documents.

Comment: @biziclop: Ah, yes, there can be an arity signal in the structure too.  Thanks.

Comment: @j.fra: Security isn't built-in at the XML or XSD levels, but see [XML Signature, XML Encryption, and XKMS](http://www.w3.org/standards/xml/security).